# Best practice on checking for property existence

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Is it better from a performance/best practice standpoint to do a check like this:

```
if ('x' in y)
```

or this:

```
if (y.x)
```

Is there any difference between them other than the first returns `false` and the second returns `undefined` which is falsey?

Comment: The two provided snippets are doing different tasks. The first snippet checks the existence of a property, the second checks the value. The second snippet will fail if the value happens to be zero, or any other intended falsy value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to look up for a property only in that object you can use `hasOwnProperty`, if look up also in the prototypes you can use `in` statement.

Yes there is a difference. If your `x` property exists but has a value as `undefined` - `y.x` will return to you `undefined` and no matter is there a `x` property or is its value `undefined`.

Look at this example, `x` exist at the object but `z` not, while accessing `y.x` and `y.z` gives the same result.

```js
const y = { x: undefined };

if ('x' in y) {
   console.log('x exists on y object');
}

console.log(y.x);
console.log(y.z);
```

So checking with `y.x` for the property **existence** is not a good approach, you may have logical issues, because every falsy value will return to you false and you can assume that property does not exist. Instead try to use either `hasOwnProperty` or `in`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `y.x` would also fetch the value after resolving if `x` is present in `y`. `'x' in y` would just do a search which would then be faster.

This is not taking into consideration how it would affect `if()`.